# Cómo agregar y eliminar id a una propiedad likes con postgres y prisma

Tags: javascript, prisma

Tengo un modelo post que tiene una propiedad likes:[]string, en esa propiedad necesito agregar los ID de usuarios para determinar quién le dió like y por otro lado necesito sacar el ID del usuario cuando quite su like del post como puedo hacer esto dado que tengo una base de datos de postgres con el orm prisma

Necesito agregar ID de un usuario a una propiedad likes sin que se repita el ID y necesito remover el ID de un usuario de esa propiedad likes